# Problems inserting auto scrolling thumbnails into accordion menu

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, accordion, thumbnails

I have an auto-scrolling thumbnail DIV that I want to insert into an accordion menu.

- [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/annUQ/3/) is the auto-scrolling thumbnail script (duplicated).
- [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/MKTxJ/) is the accordion menu.
- [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/Q2ukX/2/) is my failed attempt to combine them

I removed `position: absolute;` from the CSS to allow the two thumbnail DIV's to be on the same page without them conflicting, which may be part of the problem. Someone suggested I put `wrapAll('<div>')` into my JQ but I don't know how.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Sorry, I know trying to prevent two plugins from conflicting can be irritating, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm. solved my *own* problem. The answer was staring me in the face:
The accordion menu has a section at the very end of the JavaScript that allows you to insert code that gets initialised when a header is opened or closed:

```
onopenclose:function(header, index, state, isuseractivated){ 
//custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
    }
```

So I just put the auto scrolling thumbnail script in there. Unfortunately it builds the thumbnails from scratch every time you open a header, but at least it works now :)